# Yii - Create model on another model controller action

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-components

In my application I have a form to create an instance of `ModelA`.

However, when I submit this form, I also want to create an instance of `ModelB` with data that comes from the form submission. However, after submission, I want to show the view of created `ModelA`. In short, I want `ModelB` to be created silently.

I tried the approach of calling `actionCreate()` of `ModelB` in the `actionCreate()` method of `B`, by creating an instance of Controller `B` inside `ModelA`'s `actionCreate()`. However this doesn't seem right to me.

```
public function actionCreate(){
    $model = new ModelA;

    if(isset($_POST['ModelA'])) {           
        $model->attributes = $_POST['ModelA'];

        $modelB = new ModelB("create"); 
        $res = $modelB->actionCreate();

        if($res && $model->save()){
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }
    }       
    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Another approach is to create and save ModelB directly in the actionCreate method of ModelA. But this also doesn't seem right, since there is code repetition and it is potentitally dangerous because of user permission action-rules.

My question is: Is there a better approach, or an approach that's recommended to do this? How can I create `ModelB` on the side in a safe and efficient way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with creating multiple models in one controller action. If you have all necessary data to instantiate **ModelB** in **actionCreate** action, go ahead and do it. But your words 'create it silently' make me think you're trying to solve some problem that can be solved more efficiently without coupling these two models that much.

Just an example - when a new user is registered you want to send him a welcome email. You can hardcode that behavior right in the controller, but a more elegant solution would be to utilize the Yii's built-in mechanism of [events](http://www.sitepoint.com/yii-under-the-hood-2/). But that's just a guess, of course.

Comment: Thank you. Looking into it. :)